# On python function the dictionary is not return the full value of the key?

Tags: python, django

**App view code:**

```
def home(request):
    # return HttpResponse("<h1> This is Home Page </h1>")
    text1 = "Example Name"
    temp_dict = {'txt1': text1, 'txt2': 'Your Name'}

    return render(request, 'Second2_app/index.html', context=temp_dict)
```

**index html code:**

```
<div>
        <label for="name">User name</label>
        <input
               id="name"
               type="text"
               placeholder={{txt1}}
               name="name"
               required
               />
      </div>
```

**url I define on project file**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Second_app.urls')),
    path('Customers/', include('Second_app.urls')),
]
```

I am expecting why my desire output is not shown in the html file.......

Comment: Well, what ***is*** shown then?

Comment: Which output you are unable to see ?

Comment: I was unable to see the dictionary variable named temp_dict. I got the solution it was my mistake I placed the placeholder value without quotes.

Answer (score 1):

**Got my solution it was a silly mistake from me.**

```
<div>
 <label for="name">User name</label>
 <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="{{txt1}}" name="name" required />
</div>
```